# Pine script version change and stop reprint and repaint issue

Tags: pine-script, version, pine-script-v5, repaint, strategy-pattern

Here is a very small pine script that follows trend but I'm facing issue with this repaint and reprint issue.

```
//@version=2

strategy("PrabhuTrendStrategy", overlay=true)

tim=input('160')

out1 = security(tickerid, tim, open)
out2 = security(tickerid, tim, close)

plot(out1,color=red)
plot(out2,color=green)

longCondition = crossover(security(tickerid, tim, close),security(tickerid, tim, open))

if (longCondition)
    strategy.entry("long", strategy.long)

shortCondition = crossunder(security(tickerid, tim, close),security(tickerid, tim, open))

if (shortCondition)
    strategy.entry("short", strategy.short)
```

Answer (score 0):

In `//@version=2`, the `lookahead` argument is set to `barmerge.lookahead_on` which will cause repainting.

Upgrade your code to `v5` and use the below function for non-repainting security function shared [here](https://www.tradingview.com/script/cyPWY96u-How-to-avoid-repainting-when-using-security-PineCoders-FAQ/).

```
// Function to securely and simply call `security()` so that it never repaints and never looks ahead.
f_secureSecurity(_symbol, _res, _src) => request.security(_symbol, _res, _src[1], lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
```